# Symfony 1.4 : functional test for authenticated and unauthenticated users

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I am in the process of writing some functional tests for a symfony 1.4.19 website, using Propel ORM. Some of my pages display differently, depending on whether a user is logged in (authenticated) or not.

I have been looking at the [online documentation](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/09?orm=Propel), to see how to implement:

1. Tests that run depending on whether a user is logged in (authenticated) or not (as the case may be)
2. How to login or logout a user as part of the functional testing.

However, I can't seem to locate anything that shows how to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just connect with a user, make your test, disconnect, continue, etc ... ?

Comment: @j0k: Thats what I want to do, its just that its not clear to me how to "connect with a user" in code (in a functional test). Can you show a snippet that shows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To login:

```
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';

$browser->
  post('/login', array('signin' => array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password)))->
  with('request')->begin()->
    isParameter('module', 'sfGuardAuth')->
    isParameter('action', 'signin')->
  end()->
  with('response')->begin()->
    isStatusCode(302)->
    isRedirected()->
  end()->
  followRedirect()
;
```

To logout:

```
$browser->
  get('/logout')->
  with('request')->begin()->
    isParameter('module', 'sfGuardAuth')->
    isParameter('action', 'signout')->
  end()->
  with('response')->begin()->
    isStatusCode(302)->
    isRedirected()->
  end()->
  followRedirect()
;

// this will reset session
$browser->restart();
```

Comment: +1 for the code. Ok, thats very good. Now, all I need is the sfUser object, so that I can check whether the user is logged in or not. Thanks.

Comment: You won't have access to the sfUser object in functional test, since you are browsing your app like a browser. You need to check if there is a link like *logout* or *you're connected* (or what ever you define) in your template.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can work with that. If I come unstuck, I'll come in here and ask for help :)